# Time spent in specific Remedy queue - Need help optimizing - Previous/Current row comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, remedy

Stack Overflow Gods,

There is nothing out of the box that allows you to see how long a ticket sat in someone's queue in BMC Remedy. I have created a SQL function that does this but it's slow. Could you help me tweak it or possibly rethink my process?

Story data looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Uzu.png

So essentially what I'm doing is calculating the difference between each of the 'value' fields (dates are in epoch). I get the difference between the previous row and the current row (in seconds) then divide by 60 to give me the minutes

```
ALTER function [dbo].[getTimeAssigned]
(
    @support_group nvarchar(100),
    @request_id nvarchar(100)
)
returns bigint
as
begin

--Sample data that would be sent to the function
/*
declare @request_id nvarchar(30);
declare @support_group nvarchar(50);
set     @support_group = 'Security Support';
set     @request_id = 'INC000001049252';
*/

--can't do temp tables inside a function so I made it a variable
declare @tempTable table    
                    (
                        request_id nvarchar(30)
                        , assigned_group nvarchar(100)
                        , minutes_assigned bigint
                    )

--need to find if ticket has been closed or not
--if not we want to apply current timestamp to 'resolution_time' because i want to see how long it has been open
declare @resolution_time bigint;
select  @resolution_time = audit_date 
from    HPD_HELPDESK_AUDITLOGSYSTEM_V 
where   ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID = @request_id 
        and ([LOG] like '%resolution: resolved%' or [LOG] like '%status: Resolved%')

--means that the ticket is still open so apply current timestamp to resolution time     
if (@resolution_time is null) set @resolution_time = DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETDATE())+(3600*5)     

--slow part
--need to calculate the time difference between the previous row's assign time and the current rows assign time
--that would give me how long it spent in each queue 
;with story as
(
    select  rownum = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by audit_date)
            , [LOG]
            , ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID 
            , AUDIT_DATE [value]
    from    HPD_HELPDESK_AUDITLOGSYSTEM_V
    where   ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID  = @request_id and [LOG] like '%assigned group%'
)

--inserting into temp table to be able to aggregate only the amount assigned to @support_group and return that value
insert into @tempTable  
select      prev.ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID 
            , case
                --just renames this field to the support group i'm looking for
                when prev.[LOG]  like '%assigned group: ' + @support_group + '%' then @support_group 
                --any other group that i don't care about
                else 'Another Group'
            end [Assigned_Group]
            , (cur.value - prev.value) / 60 [minutes_assigned] --THE RUB
from        story cur
            inner join story prev 
on          prev.rownum = cur.rownum - 1

union all

select      cur.ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID
            , case
                when cur.[LOG] like '%assigned group: ' + @support_group + '%' then @support_group
                else 'Another Group'
            end [Assigned_Group]
            , (@resolution_time - cur.value)/60 [minutes_assigned] --THE RUB!!!
from        story cur
where       cur.rownum = (select MAX(story.rownum) from story)

declare @return bigint

--aggregating for return
select      @return = SUM(minutes_assigned) 
from        @tempTable  
where       assigned_group = @support_group 
group by    assigned_group, request_id 

return @return 
end
```

If I run this against tickets for the last 30 days it takes about 1 1/2 hours to complete.

Where am I going wrong?
Is it the table variable?
What could I do different to make this faster?

I believe SQL 2012 has a built-in prev/next callback but Remedy is on 2008 so I had to do it manually - am I correct on this?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the previous row, you can get that with a correlated subquery:

```
select h.*,
       (select top 1 h2.value
        from HPD_HELPDESK_AUDITLOGSYSTEM_V h2
        where h2.original_request_id = h.original_request_id and
              h2.value < h.value
        order by h2.value desc
       ) as last_value
from HPD_HELPDESK_AUDITLOGSYSTEM_V h;
```

For your calculation:

```
select h.*,
       (value -
        (select top 1 h2.value
         from HPD_HELPDESK_AUDITLOGSYSTEM_V h2
         where h2.original_request_id = h.original_request_id and
               h2.value < h.value
         order by h2.value desc
        )
       ) / 60.0 as diff_in_minutes
from HPD_HELPDESK_AUDITLOGSYSTEM_V h;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SLM? you get a lot of information about how long incidents have been in the queues, and so on, if you do [image: SLM Incident Related Service targets]

otherwise, I would go another way and create a filter running on "Get Entry", which populates the a field on the form (calculating the same value that you are attempting in SQL.). This means, that if you create a report on the remedy form, the values will be displayed. You wont be able to draw it out through SQL though, although the BMC JDBC driver would be a possible alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need to do this back end to combine with other data and metrics.

Comment: we have a similar project going on - i am unsure if that exact metric is one we are calculating - but I can query the team on it if you like?